# Selecting values through mapping table.

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have three tables **senderTable**, **recieverTable** and a **mapTable**. I am trying to write a query to get output of **senderName** and **recieverName**

**senderTable**

```
senderID
senderName
```

**recieverTable**

```
recieverID
recieverName
```

**mapTable**

```
mappingID
senderID
recieverID
```

I have following query which is not working because I do not know how to incorporate mapping table in it.

```
SELECT t_senderTable.nameFull AS "senderName", t_recieverTable.recieverName AS "recieverName" 
FROM ((dbo.t_senderTable AS t_senderTable
     INNER JOIN t_senderTable AS t_senderTable ON (t_senderTable.Kd = mapTable.senderID))
     INNER JOIN t_recieverTable AS t_recieverTabler ON (recieverTable.Id = mapTable.recieverID ))
```

Any ideas hot to do it right? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT t_senderTable.nameFull AS "senderName"
     , t_recieverTable.recieverName AS "recieverName" 
  FROM dbo.t_senderTable AS t_senderTable
 INNER JOIN mapTable
    ON t_senderTable.Id = mapTable.senderID
 INNER JOIN t_recieverTable AS t_recieverTabler
    ON mapTable.recieverID = recieverTable.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you mean by how to do it right , if its not working or what any way take a look a this :

```
   SELECT s.nameFull AS senderName, r.recieverName AS recieverName 
 FROM t_senderTable AS s
 INNER JOIN mapTable as m ON s.Kd = m.senderID
 INNER JOIN t_recieverTable  as r ON r.Id = m.recieverID
```

get rid of `()`  and replace senderTable by mapTable in inner join

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
SELECT t_senderTable.nameFull AS senderName
     , t_recieverTable.recieverName AS recieverName
  FROM dbo.t_senderTable
 INNER JOIN mapTable
    ON t_senderTable.Id = mapTable.senderID
 INNER JOIN t_recieverTable
    ON mapTable.recieverID = recieverTable.Id
```